# Why Firebase version 12.0.0 ask for PHONE_STATE permission

Tags: android, firebase, permissions, firebase-authentication

I just updated my app in BETA state to Firebase 12.0.0 and when I was going to upload a new version to the Play Store I recieved an error because my app is asking for the permission `PHONE_STATE` and I need to add a privacy policy to the application to upload the new APK.

After check different changes I saw that this permission is being ask by the last version of Firebase(12.0.0) in Android. Which doesn't allow me to continue my beta testing phase without add a privacy policy.

Why is this permission need it since the last version? Is a bug? any suggestion to continue updating my application without add a Privacy Policy( I will add it in the future, but now now).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a mistake in the packaging for 12.0.0 and will be resolved in 12.0.1.  You should revert to whatever version of Play services you were using before, or wait for 12.0.1 to be released.

Comment: Good to know, I thought it was the effect Cambridge Analytica, seen changes everywhere in policies. Lints in AS, were weren't before..

Answer (score 1):

They say fix this with 12.0.1 You can check [Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases).

Answer (score 0):

It was just fixed in 12.0.1 release.
Please, check the release notes:
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases